# Keyboard shortcut for Zoom style?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, zoom

I have been trying to look for a keyboard shortcut that would let me toggle the Zoom style from the accessibility menu. I don't think there is one. Can somebody here point me in the direction of how to build one? I can code, but I'm unsure of where to start.

Comment: Just to clarify your question: you are asking for a shortcut to toggle between fullscreen and picture-in-picture zoom style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written an AppleScript script which toggles the Zoom style:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    activate
    tell application "System Preferences"
        set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
        reveal anchor "Seeing_Zoom" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    end tell
    delay 0.5
    tell pop up button "Zoom Style:" of window "Accessibility"
        click
        if value is equal to "Fullscreen" then
            pick menu item "Picture-in-picture" of menu 1
        else
            pick menu item "Fullscreen" of menu 1
        end if
    end tell
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end tell
```

You can use Keyboard Maestro or any other script launching app to run this script on a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The zoom function on a Mac is usually `Ctrl + Scroll`, and if this isn't enabled, you can go to Accessibility > Zoom > Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom.

There's currently no keyboard shortcut for this functionality.

Hope that helps!